# The CreateAppHost task failed unexpectedly. MSB4018

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

When I try and build my ASP.NET Core project, I continue to get this error message in Visual Studio 2019. 
When I build it the second time, the error disappears.

Does anyone know what this error means and how to get rid of it?

Thanks!

```xml
<CreateAppHost AppHostSourcePath="$(AppHostSourcePath)"
                   AppHostDestinationPath="$(AppHostIntermediatePath)"
                   AppBinaryName="$(AssemblyName)$(TargetExt)"
                   IntermediateAssembly="@(IntermediateAssembly->'%(FullPath)')"
                   WindowsGraphicalUserInterface="$(_UseWindowsGraphicalUserInterface)"
                   Retries="$(CopyRetryCount)"
                   RetryDelayMilliseconds="$(CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds)"
                   />
```

[image]

Comment: You can refer to this for more information:https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/10708

Comment: On this thread: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/3832 it was mostly determined to be apps like DropBox and GoogleDrive accessing the file. In my case, I develop sometimes in a DropBox folder. Rebuilding usually works. Possible that some AV's are file monitoring and lock the file briefly for scanning.

Comment: What's the version of your project? This problem has been fixed in the latest version, you can upgrade the project to solve the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try running visual studio using 'as administrator' option.

[image]

Some of the files which required for complete building may need admin privilege for accessing them. Commonly run Visual Studio has not enough rights to access them

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. The error message for my ASP.NET Core application was

```
error MSB4018: The "CreateAppHost" task failed unexpectedly.
error MSB4018: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.NET.HostModel.AppHost.HostWriter.CreateAppHost(...
```

I tracked the issue down to the environment variable `MSBuildSDKsPath`, which pointed to an older SDK version. After unsetting the variable with `export MSBuildSDKsPath=` the problem was resolved. Alternatively, setting the variable to the most recent SDK also worked: `export MSBuildSDKsPath=C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100-rc.2.21505.57\Sdks` (just an example).

I don't remember why I set the variable in the first place, and eliminating it didn't seem to hurt either, I just removed it. It seems that in general, it is just not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that my error also noted:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '...\obj\Release\netcoreapp3.1\apphost.exe' is denied.

Deleted the obj folder and rebuild solution resolved the problem for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone still have this issue, stopping the Virus & threat protection -> Real-time protection, solve the problem.

[image]

EDIT
Use dotnet build from console

Comment: Thank you for such a simple solution.

Comment: "leaving your device vulnerale"... that's not a proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and it was because BitDefender had quarantined the apphost.exe file via Advanced Threat Protection.

Even if you add an exception the file stays locked by Windows until you REBOOT!

Answer (score 1):

What fixed for me was deleting all `bin` and `out` folder.

This was caused by using VSCode as admin. Apparently after I build solution with VSCode as admin, some gets messed up resulting with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

For the applications running in dotnet core, fire a command `dotnet clean` to clean up all your binaries. Then dotnet build and you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

It was occurred in `dotnet build` on docker (dotnet-sdk-3.1, dist:CentOS 8.1).

Log:

```
/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/3.1.111/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(393,5): error MSB4018: The "CreateAppHost" task failed unexpectedly. [<PathToCsproj>.csproj]
 System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '/<PathToCsprojDir>/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/<AssemblyName>' because it is being used by another process. [<PathToCsproj>.csproj]
    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(FileMode mode, FileShare share, String originalPath) in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/IO/FileStream.Unix.cs:line 86 [<PathToCsproj>.csproj]
    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options) in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/IO/FileStream.cs:line 244 [<PathToCsproj>.csproj]
    at System.IO.FileSystem.CopyFile(String sourceFullPath, String destFullPath, Boolean overwrite) in /_/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/FileSystem.Unix.cs:line 25 [<PathToCsproj>.csproj]
    at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite) in /_/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/File.cs:line 77 [<PathToCsproj>.csproj]
    at Microsoft.NET.HostModel.AppHost.BinaryUtils.CopyFile(String sourcePath, String destinationPath) [<PathToCsproj>.csproj]
    at Microsoft.NET.HostModel.AppHost.HostWriter.CreateAppHost(String appHostSourceFilePath, String appHostDestinationFilePath, String appBinaryFilePath, Boolean windowsGraphicalUserInterface, String assemblyToCopyResorcesFrom) [<PathToCsproj>.csproj]
    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.CreateAppHost.ExecuteCore() [<PathToCsproj>.csproj]
    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute() [<PathToCsproj>.csproj]
    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [<PathToCsproj>.csproj]
    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [<PathToCsproj>.csproj]
```

Solution:

Add `CopyRetryCount` environment variable.
After that, it works with warning.

```
export CopyRetryCount=100
dotnet build --verbosity quiet -c Debug
```

Acknowledgments:

This answer may be off-topic, but it has similar message.
This question has parameter to solve my problem, that was very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

VS sometimes looses the permission to access some files in the Obj directory. There are two possible solutions for this:

1. Close VS and restart as Admin, so that the permissions are granted again

[image]

2. Close VS > Delete the project Obj folder > Open VS > rebuild project (if VS didn't do it automatically)

Answer (score 0):

I was running the code inside shared directory, moving the folder out of shared directory and running the dotnet again solved the error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the folder path was too long. I simply shifted my project to a short path directory i.e., `D:/MyProject1` and it works.

Answer (score -2):

due to multiple sdk version downloaded in system.

remove that from the c:/

then it remove error