# Microsoft web app with ASP.NET Core 6.0 failure

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, web-applications

When launching my app, it crashes and I get an error

> 'CreateAppHost' task failed unexpectedly

I have sent the code to a friend, and they launched it without any issues. What could be the problem on my device?

I can share the code if anyone can help.

I tried to launch the app; it is supposed to start normally, but it crashes instantly. Now, even my Visual Studio is giving problems. I can't update or uninstall the application.

Comment: Can u share your code ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you could try these workarounds: 1)repairing visual studio. 2)reinstalling .net core SDK 3)delete bin and obj folder data and rebuild your project  4)try to run visual studio as admin. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61067765/the-createapphost-task-failed-unexpectedly-msb4018 if possible please share reproducible sample